# Custom category URL rewriting

Tags: categories, pages, url-rewriting, urls

Here is the situation: let say I have a page called Press and that page has this url: www.example.com/press-center

Now, let say that I have a category Press (slug is press) and subcategory called News and it's content is available on www.example.com/category/press/news

I want to rewrite the category URL so every time someone types www.example.com/category/press/news should get:
www.example.com/press-center/news.

If there is a post in this category, then the URL should look like:
www.example.com/press-center/news/some-post-in-this-category

Is this possible and how?